# Getting the current time of an SVGAnimation element in SVG Tiny 1.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an SVG Animation element.

```
...
<animation id="playlist" begin="indefinite" dur="60.0" repeatDur="indefinite" width="1920" height="1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" xlink:href="playlist.svg"/>
...
```

Within playlist.svg, there are several svg video elements. For example:

```
...
<video begin="0;item_8.end" dur="10.0" width="1920" height="1080" xlink:href="files/content/movie.mp4" id="item_1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" />
...
```

Everything runs fine, these video clips run continuously without error.

I'm trying to get the elapsed time of the playlist. We've tried using

```
var elapsed_time = document.getElementById('playlist').getCurrentTime();
//  or
var elapsed_time = $('#playlist').getCurrentTime();
```

but it's returning

```
$("#playlist").getCurrentTime is not a function
```

We either need the method to get the current time of the playlist, or the name of the variable that holds elapsed time, or a code snippet that will generate this for us.

FYI, none of this is in a browser; it's on a device that runs SVG files and generates logs, so we don't have access to Firebug, console.log, etc., but we can alert() and view errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're looking for is [getCurrentTime()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/svgudom.html#svg__SVGSVGElement) on the root svg element. There isn't one per animation, just for the whole document fragment.

Comment: getCurrentTime on the root svg element returns the elapsed time since the whole document loaded. It's unbelievable that there is no way to see how far along in an animation you are. It seems to me to be a necessary property. I suppose that I we could take the root element time, subtract the time it takes to begin the animation, and then mod it by the playlist length, but that seems inaccurate and this calculation must be precise.